Spatie/laravel-pdf Route fails from browser but works from the CLI for saving simple test pdf
I have been struggling with an issue for the past few days now, regarding using spatie/laravel-pdf on my remote ubuntu 22.04 server running openlitespeed with php 8.2 with nvm node.
I made an MWE laravel project to investigate this: https://github.com/kaspernowak/laravel-pdf
What I fail to understand, is that when I try to save a test pdf like this:
Route::get('/test-pdf', function () {
    $htmlContent = "<h1>Hello World!</h1><p>This is a test PDF generated from HTML.</p>";
    $pdfPath = public_path('hello_world.pdf');

    Pdf::html($htmlContent)
        ->withBrowsershot(function ($browsershot) {
            $browsershot 
                ->setIncludePath('$PATH:'.config('browsershot.include_path')) // Necessary for this to work with nvm.
        }) 
        ->save($pdfPath);
        
        return 'PDF generated and saved to ' . $pdfPath;
});

It just works from my local ubuntu machine when navigating to /test-pdf, with a local install of nvm and puppeteer with node.
When I  pull my repository on my remote ubuntu server with the same puppeteer setup, I always get this error when navigating to /test-pdf:
Error Output:
================
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!

TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

I have tried everything from the pptr troubleshooting, without luck.
The weird thing is, that when I run puppeteer from the CLI as the executable user of the laravel project vhost on the remote server, the /test-pdf just works and a pdf is saved to my public directory.
Does anyone know what could be causing this issue, when it works from the CLI but not from the browser?
